# Regular Expressions - My Code Does Not Behave

Tags: regex, substring

```
<p>Blockbuster event so big that the excerpt will not even fit into the allotted space.</p> 
<p> The post 
     <a rel="nofollow" href="http://example.com/event/sample-event/">Sample Event</a> 
    appeared first on 
     <a rel="nofollow" href="http://example.com">abc</a>.
</p>

$desc = preg_replace('/<p>(.*)<\/p>/i', '$1', $event->description);
$desc = substr($desc, 0, strpos($desc, 'The post'));
```

Hey, I'm trying to strip tags and extract only the part until 'The post'. I have tried `/<p>(.*)<\/p>/` but this returns both parts of the description. To achieve the end result I had to take a sub string. Is there a regex that takes care of this so I don't need to use substr()?

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Make the expression "[ungreedy](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)":

```
$desc = preg_replace('/<p>(.*)<\/p>/Ui', '$1', $event->description);
```

or

```
$desc = preg_replace('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/i', '$1', $event->description);
```

If you want to keep just the contents of the first `<p>` tag, it may be simpler to `preg_match` and keep the result:

```
preg_match('/<p>(.*)<\/p>/Ui', $event->description, $results);
$desc = $results[1];
```

Here's a demo: https://ideone.com/KFLdnI